# Override or extend serializer groups defined by annotation in Symfony2

Tags: symfony, jmsserializerbundle, jms-serializer

I'm using JMS Serializer in a Symphony 2 project and I am using serializer groups defined in Annotations.

For one specific case, I would like to change or at least add one group depending on runtime parameters (i.e. checking user authorisation).

I am also using annotations to not interact directly with the serializer, my methods simply return the objects.

Is this possible? I found nothing in the documentation that makes me believe I can override the annotations.